# Menus and layout a mess on mini upgrade 2.5.28 to 3.3.6

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, upgrade, layout

I'm running a lamp stack on ubuntu 14.04. Just upgraded my local site from 2.5.28 to 3.3.6. It upgraded okay but all the menus are messed up. The formatting is shocking!

[image: See menus top right and layout of save boxes]

[image: poor formatting- unworkable]

Can anyone advise as to why the formatting of my backend is so bad? I've tried changing the template but it doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried clearing both Joomla and browser cache? Also, when changing admin template, does it still look weird?

Comment: Thanks you're right it was down to the backend templates. Some kind of conflict. Uninstalled all but isis default one. Cleared cached of Joomla and browser. Now perfect! :-)

Comment: @user3258396 - Please add your process as a proper answer and accept it so other users can benefit from it, should they have the same issue ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the admin template in your screenshot is the default **Joomla 2.5** template called "Bluestork", and it's not made for Joomla 3. Joomla 3.x comes with a new default template called "Isis", so the first thing to do is to set "isis" as default admin template in <kbd>Extensions</kbd> > <kbd>Template Manager</kbd>:

[image: Setting default template]

That will probably solve the problem, but if it doesn't, here's a couple of other things to try:

1. Clear your browsers cache
2. Clear Joomla cache (<kbd>System</kbd> > <kbd>Clear cache</kbd>)
3. Copy the folder `administrator/templates/isis` and all of it's content from another Joomla 3.x installation (or from the full installation package available [here](http://www.joomla.org/download.html)) to the same location on your local site, and replace any existing files if prompted.

Comment: Thanks both your. Answers have greatly helped me :-) sorted !

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution to this I discovered, which is to check that the admin user has the correct template selected. Changing from the user's default Bluestork to Isis sorted this issue out for me.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. May well have sorted it out. I'm up and running again now anyway so cannot confirm that your fix works,but I imagine it would.